# When we join two past events, must we use the perfect participle or can we use the present participle as well?

Tags: perfect-constructions, participles

When two incidents happen in past one after another we use past perfect tense.

> By the time she got to the theatre, the play had already begun.

Is this rule also apply when we make a sentence using participle? I mean when we join two sentence happened in past one after another do we use only perfect participle or can we use present participle as well?

If we have these sentences:

> We started early. We arrived at noon.

Joining using **present participle**:

> Starting early, we arrived at noon.

Or joining using **perfect participle**:

> Having started early,we arrived at noon.

Comment: Yes, perfectly acceptable. I don't see anything wrong with your usage.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a “rule” or even usual that “when two incidents happen in the past one after another we use past perfect tense”. On the contrary; in a narrative of past events we ordinarily cast all events in the simple past:

> Sarah **showered** and **changed** into her nicest clothes. She **dined** at the little Greek restaurant down the block, and then **called** a cab. Traffic **was** heavy and she **arrived** at the theatre a little late.

We use the past perfect when in the course of a past narrative we wish to mention an event which occurred before the point our narrative has currently reached.

> ... Traffic **was** heavy, and when she **arrived** at the theatre, the play ***had*** already ***begun***. She **stood** at the back of the auditorium until the first intermission, and then **took** her second-row seat.

Which construction you use, simple or perfect, depends on when the event you mention occurs ***relative to*** your current standpoint: your ‘reference time’ (RT), the time you are talking about. Simple constructions are used for events **at** RT, and perfect constructions for events which occur **before** RT.

A participial clause has no tense of its own—it ‘borrows’ its time reference from its head clause—but it works the same way. If the event it presents takes place **at** RT, we use a ‘simple’ present participle:

> We retired at sundown and rose at dawn for a hurried breakfast. **Starting** early, we made good speed in the cool morning air and arrived at noon.

But if the event takes place **before** RT, we use a participial perfect:

> We retired at sundown. The next day we made good speed in the cool morning air, and **having left** early we arrived at noon.